# Agregar una demora entre dos eventos en Vb

Tags: vb.net, vb, vb6

La cosa es esta; tengo tres botones. Quiero que cuando el usuario de clic en uno de ellos obtenga un numero al azar del 1 al 20. Si el numero al azar que regresa es 5 entonces quiero que espere dos segundos y luego los otros botones se pongan en rojo. Utilicé este código para registrar el tiempo entre que da clic al botón y sale 5.

```
   Function IniciarTURCE() As Integer
       ITUR_CE = Environment.TickCount
       Return ITUR_CE
   End Function
   Public Tiempo_TURCE As Integer
   Function Duracion_Turce()
       Tiempo_TURCE = Environment.TickCount
       Return (Tiempo_TURCE - IniciarTURCE())
End Function
```

Tengo también mi subrutina para hacer el cambio en el color de los botones

```
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Button3.Enabled = True
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Green
End Sub
```

Pero no sé como llamar a mi funcion que mide el tiempo para que tenga esa demora, alguien podría ayudarme?Se los agradezco de antemano

Comment: Sleep(5000) demora 5000 ms (o 5 segundos)

Comment: @Duston eso lo pondría antes de la subrutina de cambio de color en los botones?

Comment: Lo siento, leí la pregunta otra vez.  Sleep(2000) demora 2 segundos. De lo que dijo, despues de la regresa del 5 y antes de la subutina que cambia los colores.

Comment: @Duston Lo he puesto y me marca que Sleep() no ha sido declarada, al parecer no es una función como tal en esta versión de vb y no puedo llamarla. Tengo vb 2010

Comment: Tal vez System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) ?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona pero cada que hago eso el programa se congela primero y luego ya sigue con el codigo :/ eso afecta por completo lo que necesito hacer.